# Stopping a Tkinter window without closing it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a python script that shows an animation of the evolution of a path-finding algorithm and i am wondering how to stop the main loop once it has reached a certain condition.

my basic idea (without any of my actual code) is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, background="black")
canvas.pack()

def initialise():
    <some code to initialise everything on the canvas>

def move():
    <some code for move()>

root.after(1000,move)
root.mainloop()
```

i would like to be able to test a condition in the function move() that allows me to stop the Tkinter main loop but still leave the window open so you can see it, and then be able to do other things after (not with the window tho, it doesnt matter if that is unchangeable, just so long as it is visible until the user closes the window)

so basically similar to this:

```
while true:   # this represents the Tkinter mainloop
    <do something>
    if <final condition>:
        break

<some other operations on data>  # this happens after mainloop stops
```

Comment: You don't need to stop or pause the main loop, you need to stop the `move()` animation.

Comment: how do i do that? `move()` just calculates the updated position for everything on the canvas and then repositions it

Comment: Presumably you're calling `move()` repeatedly. Make that only continue while the stop condition hasn't yet been reached. It's a bit hard to be any more specific since your code is just placeholders.

Comment: wait, yes you are right, i am calling `move()` at the bottom of `move()`, if i just put a condition `if <something>: move()` then if the condition isnt met, will my loop just stop? sorry, i didnt realise it would be that simple, i was confused by the "mainloop" part and thought that might keep going, i am just learning how to use Tkinter.. i will try that

Comment: Yep, that's all you have to do.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the stupid question, i should have worked that out myself! i just thought there woudl be some kind of root.stop() function i had to call or something.. if you want the extra reputation, then make an official answer and i will accept it. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop `mainloop` without destroying the window. That's the fundamental nature of Tkinter.

What you can do instead is simply stop the animation. You can do that exactly like you propose: add a flag or final condition in your `move` method.

```
def move():
    if some_condition:
        return
    ...
    root.after(1000, move)
```